# Reading Bluetooth input stream in android

Tags: android, input, stream, bluetooth

I am developing an application that read data from biometric devices using Bluetooth when I send request to biometric device for sending data, biometric device show response with updating its display screen but when I call function for read input stream for getting response the function `in_stream.available()` return 0. I am not able to trace out the root of problem. I have test same biometric device with some other app it work fine.
Help me if any one have idea about this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do no use available() method. It is broken in most implementations. You should be constantly reading  with read() or read(byte []). If the protocol lets you know the size of the expected data (i.e. some first bytes telling how much data is coming afterwards) you can just read that amount of data.

If the amount of data is unknown or you expect asynchronous data comming then you should manage the writing/reading to/from the streams in a separate thread. This does not only applies to Bluetooth but also to any basic stream handling (network, files, etc.)

Comment: Yikes.  Others say that inputstream.read() is broken on Android - it doesn't release when the socket is closed - so you should always check available before calling read on Android.